# VBA to combine cell comments from duplicate rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine multiple cell comments together if they are duplicates.

Currently my macro imports cable length data, then removes the duplicates after it counts the amount of duplicate rows. Example: Qty 7 of 100Ft will be just one row of 700Ft of cable. The issue I am having is each row has a comment of where that cable was imported from. After its combined it only keeps one of the comments. How can I combine the comments?

```
'Import Data
    If ws.Range("C" & c) = Chr(42) Then
        ws.Range("H" & c & ":L" & c).Copy Destination:=wsC.Range("A" & lr) '* New Circuit
        wsC.Range("B" & lr).AddComment wb.Name
        lr = lr + 1
    End If


'Remove Duplicates
    For x = lastrow To 7 Step -1
        For Y = 7 To lastrow
            If (.Cells(x, 1) = .Cells(Y, 1) And .Cells(x, 3) = .Cells(Y, 3) And _
                .Cells(x, 4) = .Cells(Y, 4) And .Cells(x, 5) = .Cells(Y, 5)) And x > Y Then
                .Cells(Y, 2) = .Cells(x, 2) + .Cells(Y, 2)
                Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Y
    Next x
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the comments with line feeds.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Summate()

   Const FIRSTROW = 7

   Dim ws As Worksheet, s As String
   Dim lastrow As Long, x As Long, y As Long
   
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   With ws
       lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       For x = lastrow To FIRSTROW Step -1
          For y = FIRSTROW  to x-1
             If .Cells(y, 1) = .Cells(x, 1) And _
                .Cells(y, 3) = .Cells(x, 3) And _
                .Cells(y, 4) = .Cells(x, 4) And _
                .Cells(y, 5) = .Cells(x, 5) Then
                    ' summate qu
                    .Cells(y, 2) = .Cells(y, 2) + .Cells(x, 2)
                    ' concat comments
                    If .Cells(x, 2).Comment Is Nothing Then
                        ' skip
                    Else
                        s = .Cells(x, 2).Comment.Text
                        If .Cells(y, 2).Comment Is Nothing Then
                           .Cells(y, 2).AddComment s
                        Else
                           ' insert text
                           .Cells(y, 2).Comment.Text vbLf & s, Len(s) + 1, False
                        End If
                    End If
                    .Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete 'test with .Interior.Color = vbRed
                    Exit For
              End If
          Next
       Next
   End With
   MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```